# Bug? #1146 - Table 'xxx.xxxxx' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1146

I am using windows XP. I am creating a table in phpMyAdmin using its built-in create table feature, 
my database name is `ddd`.

It generates the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE  `ddd`.`mwrevision` (

`asd` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`sddd` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

and the following error shows up:

```
MySQL said:     
#1146 - Table 'ddd.mwrevision' doesn't exist
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: try to create simple table with one column and with out primay/key/constraint

Comment: @Ravi, i tried it, but no help!, this is the code: CREATE TABLE ddd`.`mwrevision` ( `nnn` INT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = INNODB; and the same error

Comment: for fire query what app/cmd/shell/browser/WB using?

Comment: phpmyadmin, windows xp, chrome, should i tell anything else?

Comment: from cmd/shell try `create database a;
CREATE TABLE  a.mwrevision (asd INT );`

Comment: Did you verify you have required privileges on that database?
I am able to create the table (database name is not ddd though)

Comment: i am logged in as root and i am using the same account for everything, its the first time i have encountered this, @Ravi, i dont know how to use mysql promt so i used phpmyadmin to create the db and add the table and it worked!

Comment: run -> cmd -> just go to %mysql%/bin and type as i post in answer

Comment: can you try removing back ticks (`) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I also had same problem in past. All had happend after moving database files to new location and after updating mysql server. All tables with InnoDB engine disappeared from my database. I was trying to recreate them, but mysql told me `1146: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist` all the time until I had recreated my database and restarted mysql service.

I think there's a need to read about InnoDB table binaries.

Comment: my problem was similar to you but it was a little different, the phpmyadmin table drop down (which appears on the left) was showing me 11 tables while on the right side only 10 tables were visible, i dont know what was actually the problem may be a bug with phpmyadmin or a bug with mysql but anyways i solved the problem long ago, but using the method you specified. so marking your answer as selected :)

Comment: The key part here seems to be the last sentence - recreate your db and restart mysql.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and can't get a good tip for this over the web, so I shared this for you and for all who needs.

In my situation I copy a database (all files: frm, myd) to the data folder in MySQL data folder (using Wamp at home). All thing was OK until I want to create a table and have the error `#1146 Table '...' doesn't exist!`.

I use Wamp 2.1 with MySQL version 5.5.16.

My solution:

1. Export the database to file;
2. verify if exported file is really OK!!;
3. drop the database where I have issues;
4. create a new database with the same name that the last;
5. import the file to the database.

FOR ME IS PROBLEM SOLVED. Now I can create tables again without errors.

Comment: By copying frm,myd myi files you have only copied the database schema. Actual data resides in `ibdata1` file in case of INNODB tables. If you have copied the `ibdata1` and `ib_logfile?` files it would have worked.

Answer (score 7):

Restarting MySQL works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I ran this command even if the table wasn't visible in PhpMyAdmin :

`DROP TABLE mytable`

then

`CREATE TABLE....`

Worked for me !

Comment: THIS needs to be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check filenames.

You might need to **create a new database** in phpmyadmin that matches the database you're trying to import.

Comment: Filenames do not matter at all.

Comment: @Shaheer Solved for you, but what about everyone else?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried to create a table in mysql and got the same error. I restarted mysql server and ran the command and was able to create/migrate table after restating.

Answer (score 1):

Today i was facing same problem. I was in very difficult situation but what id did i create a table with diffrent name e.g (modulemaster was not creating then i create modulemaster1) and after creating table i just do the rename table.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today. I was trying to create a table `users`, and was prompted that `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table users doesn't exist`, which did not make any sense, because I was just trying to create the table!!

I then tried to drop the table by typing `DROP TABLE users`, knowing it would fail because it did not exist, and I got an error, saying `Unknown table users`. After getting this error, I tried to create the table again, and magically, it successfully created the table!

My intuition is that I probably created this table before and it was not completely cleared somehow. By explicitly saying `DROP TABLE` I managed to reset the internal state somehow? But that is just my guess.

In short, try DROP whatever table you are creating, and CREATE it again.

Answer (score 1):

As **pprakash** mentions above, copying the **table.frm files** AND the **ibdata1** file was what worked for me.

In short:

1. Shut your DB explorer client (e.g. Workbench).
2. Stop the MySQL service (Windows host).
3. Make a safe copy of virtually everything!
4. Save a copy of the table file(s) (eg **mytable.frm**) to the schema data folder (e.g. MySQL Server/data/{yourschema}).
5. Save a copy of the **ibdata1** file to the data folder (i.e., MySQL Server/data).
6. Restart the MySQL service.
7. Check that the tables are now accessible, queryable, etc. in your DB explorer client.

After that, all was well. (Don't forget to backup if you have success!)

Answer (score 0):

Column names must be unique in the table. You cannot have two columns named `asd` in the same table.

Comment: I think this is only due to anonymization.

Comment: it didnt work i tried sddd for the second column name, but still the same effect

Comment: @gumbo, anonymization? what is this?

Comment: did you create database/schema ddd?

Comment: @user503148: Anonymization is the process of making data anonymous. These database/table/row names are not those you’re actually using, are they?

Comment: @user503148 Anonymization is when you replace certain strings in the offending code when posting it online, so as not to reveal security-relevant information. User names and passwords that are hard-coded into the source code are usual candidates for that.

Comment: @Tommy, yes the database exists and it contains 46 tables

Comment: @Oswald, no i didn't replace anything, i copy pasted "exact" same code, even the table name, and the database is also the same name, "ddd", i created it for temproray usage and after i am done with it, i will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

run from CMD & %path%=set to mysql/bin

`mysql_upgrade -u user -ppassword`

Comment: make sure you are on localhost this will try to upgrade

Comment: I just got a lot of errors Table 'xxx.u8nxi_updates' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had same problem, but on Linux Server. Database was crashed, and I recovered it from backup, based on simply copying `/var/lib/mysql/*` (analog mysql DATA folder in wamp). After recovery I had to create new table and got mysql error #1146. I tried to restart mysql, and it said it could not start. I checked mysql logs, and found that mysql simply had no access rigths to its DB files. I checked owner info of /var/lib/mysql/*, and got `'myuser:myuser'` (myuser is me). But it should be `'mysql:adm'` (so is own developer machine), so I changed owner to 'mysql:adm'. And after this mysql started normally, and I could create tables, or do any other operations.

So after moving database files or restoring from backups check access rigths for mysql.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was facing this was because I had two "models.py" files which contained slightly different fields. 
I resolved it by:

1. deleting one of the models.py files
2. correcting references to the deleted file
3. then running manage.py syncdb

Answer (score 0):

I  got this issue after copying mytable.idb table file from  another location. To fix this problem I did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mydatabase.mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Copy mytable.idb

```
ALTER TABLE mydatabase.mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Restart MySql

Comment: Does't work ``Error Code: 1146. Table 'wp_commentmeta' doesn't exist``

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It happened after windows start up error, it seems some files got corrupted due to this. I did import the DB again from the saved script and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because of a trigger not working..Worked after I deleted the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, MySQL's parameter; `lower_case_table_names` was configured `= 0`.

It causes queries related with using upper cases will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a table name upper/lower case issue. I had to make sure that table case name matched in a delete query, table `notifications` was not the same as `Notifications`. I fixed it by matching table name case with query and what MySQLWorkbench reported.

What is wierd is that this error showed up in a worked sql statement. Don't know what caused this case sensitivity. Perhaps an auto AWS RDS update.

Answer (score 0):

if you are modifying mysql bin->data dir's and after that, your database import will not works

**so you need to close wamp and after that start wamp**

now database import will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have a trigger that is trying to do something with the table mentioned in the error. I was receiving `Error Code: 1146. Table 'exampledb.sys_diagnotics' doesn't exist` on insert queries to another table in my production database. I exported the table schemas of my production database then searched for instances of `exampledb.sys_diagnotics` the schema SQL and found a debugging insert statement I had added to a table trigger in my development environment but this debug statement had been copied to production. The `exampledb.sys_diagnotics` table was not present on my production database. The error was resolved by removing the debug statement in my table trigger.