# Add-Migration won't detect changes to foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

EF Migrations can't seem to detect my changes to the model, as it just generates an empty `Up() / Down()` when running `Add-Migration`.

The database is not out of sync with my migrations.

**Migration file:**
[image: Migration file]

**__migrationhistory table:**
[image: __migrationhistory table]

### Before

```
public class House {
    public virtual ICollection<Person> UsedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Car {
    // ...
}

public class Person {
    public int? UsingId { get; set; }
    public virtual House Using { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Using)
                .WithMany(t => t.UsedBy)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.UsingId);
```

### After

```
public class House {
    // removed
}

public class Car {
    // added
    public virtual ICollection<Person> UsedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public int? UsingId { get; set; }
    // changed type
    public virtual Car Using { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Using)
                .WithMany(t => t.UsedBy)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.UsingId);
```

Comment: I can confirm this problem. Renaming the `Using` property is a working "solution". Maybe this is a bug in EF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in my comment I could reproduce this, but renaming the `Using` property also helped.
If that is not an option you could use the following code added manually to the migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.People", "UsingId", "dbo.Houses");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.People", "UsingId", "dbo.Cars", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.People", "UsingId", "dbo.Cars");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.People", "UsingId", "dbo.Houses", "Id");
}
```

This is based on what `Add-Migration` creates when renaming the property.

Comment: Perhaps we should report this bug :)

Comment: Something funky is going on when I manually alter the `Up() / Down()` methods. I'm getting the following error: Table 'mydb.dbo.people' doesn't exist. I checked the database and it's there. When I empty the `Up() / Down()` everything works fine again...

Comment: Renaming the property results in the same "Table 'mydb.dbo.people' doesn't exist." error :(

Comment: Thats strange. Did not happen in my test project. Try to genreate the SQL script an execute it manually via SSMS?

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm renaming the table with `this.ToTable("...")`. I'll have to test that out in an isolated case. Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Hmm seems it's now MySQL that the problem. I generated the SQL script and tried to run it on the server but got the same error. Found others getting the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869476/error-code-1146-but-table-does-exist so moving forward-ish :/

Comment: MySQL? Don't you mean MS SQL?

Comment: We've gone a bit off topic :) But I found the solution here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69649
I had to add `CodeGenerator = new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();` (had the others). So Renamed the properties and looked at what was generated (as suggested) then edited them manually to fit and BAM great success!

Comment: I confirm this is working also in VS 2017 (even tough it's not a VS issue)