# MySql Error: 1146 xampp I see schema but can't access table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a really weird problem. I am not entirely sure how it happen, and I do not have any viggest idea on where to start.

I am running `XAMPP` 1.8.3-5. Right now both on MySQL Workbench and also phpMyAdmin I can see and view schema and the tables in side it.  However when I try to select schema.table, I get a return `ERROR CODE: 1146`.

I went in to `XMAPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` to make sure that the data exist and is stored where it belongs.

So I intended to export and back up the DB through phpMyAdmin / Workbench and than reimport it.  However when I tried to do that i get the following

```
Couldn't execute 'show create table `actions`
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `actions`': Table 'resource.actions' doesn't exist (1146)
```

What troubles me is the physical data is there.  Through phpMyAdmin / Workbench I can also see the schema along with the table inside just can't do anything with it.

Could this be a permission problem? Anyway to recover this?  Thank you.

Show Databases;

```
+-------------------------+
| Database                |
+-------------------------+
| information_schema      |
| cdcol                   |
| drupal_sandbox          |
| mysql                   |
| performance_schema      |
| phpmyadmin              |
| resource                |
| test                    |
|     |
+-------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342201/bug-1146-table-xxx-xxxxx-doesnt-exist

Comment: @Programmerman yes but not exactly. I am not trying to create table within a schema.  I have the schema just can't access nor can I do datadump.  I did however try to recreate the table as suggested but it doesn't work... thnaks

Comment: run this command and tell me what you see ...show databases;

Comment: @Programmerman Sorry for the late reply was out of town + couldn't get mysql command to work.  I have edit my question with the output.. thanks again for take the time...

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: @Programmerman I am using linux

Comment: Try setting permission

Comment: @Programmerman Please elaborate?

Comment: Never mind don't think that is necessary for databases, check this link it should resolve your problem http://www.linux.org/threads/resolving-mysql-error-1146-table-doesnt-exist-when-doing-backup.2480/