# Restore MySql databases and error 1146

Tags: mysql, database

I have got a number of database on a local server. The server was cleaned up (disc cleanup) and mysql service was stopped. I tried to run the service again but it didn't work so I re-installed wampp. After installing it I could connect to mysql server and I see the databases and tables but it generates error 1146 once a table is clicked to open. Is there any way to restore the data from each database?

By the way, I have got a backup from mysql/bin folder which has been taken before installing wampp again.

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342201/bug-1146-table-xxx-xxxxx-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

try to

- Export the db
- Delete them
- Create them again with same names
- Import the data into them

Is it possible to paste some of the exact error not only the code?

Comment: Now try my proposed solution and give us some feedback.

Comment: what do u mean by export? you mean copy the entire database folder from bin directory or export using a tools like phpmyadmin? Actually, the second one is impossible since none of the tables are readable.