# Wordpress - Is there a way to recover the table wp_term_relationships?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to help a Non-Profit Organization with their site (which is built with Wordpress) that suddenly became "buggy"/odd: menus were missing, categories were empty, etc.

I'm no expert around Wordpress, so the first thing I did was to turn on the DEBUG mode and I get this message:

```
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: 
[Table 'racidb.rc_term_relationships' doesn't exist]
```

So, next thing I did was check on the database (MySQL). When I login on phpMyAdmin, I can see the table on the left column but when I try to browse the content, I get this message error:

```
 #1146 - Table 'racidb.rc_term_relationships' doesn't exist
```

I tried to repair the table, drop it and delete it's content with no luck. I keep getting the error #1146.

Unfortunately, there are no backups on the database so I just can't upload the table again.

According to them, the error happened at the same time in which Wordpress was updated to 4.2.6 (they got the automatic email of Wordpress the day this issue appeared).

My questions:
1) Does anyone know what might have happened?
2) Is there any way I can recover the data from MySQL?
3) Is there any way to recover the table "xx_term_relationships"? Besides creating manually all the records.

Many thanks in advanced!

Comment: What happens if you export the database from phpMyAdmin?  Does the export file contain the table and its data?  Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342201/bug-1146-table-xxx-xxxxx-doesnt-exist) you may have to recreate the database to fix the problem (assuming you don't have access to the data files themselves)

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. If I exportación the complete database, it doesn't even include the table structure. The export ignores the table.  I know that the odds are against us, but I don't want to give up that easily

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. But i had the same problem , my client website(WordPress) automatically gets updated.it was build on `3.2` version of WordPress. 
Some of the tables gets corrupted and its appear in `structures` also in `left side of tables`.

**To Solve This problem you need to repair your `tables`**

1. Go to database > table structure.
2. Check the table which needs to repair.
3. select `Repair Table` from dropdown.

   [image: See Snap Shot]

Comment: Hi @Norman, thanks for your suggestion. I only see the table on the left column of phpMyAdmin, it doesn't appear where you are showing. But anyways, I executed the following query: **REPAIR TABLE `rc_term_relationships`**
But the answer I get is the same: **Table 'racidb.rc_term_relationships' doesn't exist** / **Operation failed**

Comment: Do u have access to check `mysql\data\Databasename` folder ? if you found some files like `wp_term_relationships.MYI` , `wp_term_relationships.MYD`, `wp_term_relationships.frm` copy these there files and paste it in your local server `mysql\data\Databasename` folder if found . if these are not exists then you cant do anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. They are just using some simple hosting (I can't even use SSH on the server nor in the database server). I'll try to ask them from the Hosting's support team. Thanks!