# MySQL tables listed in phpmyadmin side navigation but can't access them

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I moved my files from an SSD to another one so had to copy the files & database.

The problem began when I wasn't able to see the tables of my old database after running the `cp` command for copying the database.

The command line query :

```
cp -R /my-old-media/var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql
```

On searching the internet a lot the issues seems to be due to the 'ib' & 'frm' files which were not correctly copied.
Please refer image attached for the problem.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug? #1146 - Table 'xxx.xxxxx' doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342201/bug-1146-table-xxx-xxxxx-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Seems more like a server issue, than a programming issue. Might fit better at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?